# How to make SR Latch via RxJS 6?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs6

I want to make SR latch via RxJS. It should take 2 streams (#1 and #2) and emit only if #1 emit something.

Then it should ignore #1 and listen to #2 until it emits something. Then it should "reset" (EDIT: means stop emitting observables, but keep the subscription) and start listening to #1.

I made a quick jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fczjusqn/11/ with the bug - if you press start several times it will make interval start several times.

This is emulation of pausable process with a bit complex setup logic in my real app.

Obligatory code:

```
// const start$ = ...
// const stop$ = ...

start$.pipe(
  flatMap(() => {
    // some setup logic...
    // ...creating another stream...
    // ...still setting up...
    return Rx.interval(1000)
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(stop$)
      )
    })    
  ).subscribe(() => console.log('interval'))
```

Comment: When you say reset, do you mean cancel the subscription and resubscribe? Or just ignore but keep the subscription?

Comment: @IngoBürk it should keep the subscription. The idea is to hide this implementation detail and pass obervable further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest creating an `input$` observable that fires only changed value from start to stop or stop to start :

```
const start$ = Rx.fromEvent(document.querySelector('#start'), 'click').pipe(op.mapTo(true));

const stop$ = Rx.fromEvent(document.querySelector('#stop'), 'click').pipe(op.mapTo(false));

const input$ = Rx.merge(start$, stop$).pipe(op.distinctUntilChanged());
```

This way when you click multiple times on start or stop it will be simply ignored. Using this observable, you can simply use the stream as you already been using it.

[Here is a fork of your example with my suggestion.](https://jsfiddle.net/r4vfqo39/37/)

Comment: Just tried, it works, thanks! off-topic question - why did you use switchMap instead of flatMap?

Comment: `switchMap` will abort the previous `Observable` and replace it by the new one everytime the value changes. As in this case there is no reason to keep the previous `Observable`, I used `switchMap`.
Here is a fork of your initial code that highlights the issue with `flatMap` : https://jsfiddle.net/7njLwa03/8/
(click multiple times on start, you will end up with multiple observables subscription running in parallel)